# If $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=i\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$ then $\overline{f }$ is analytic (exercise from Ahlfors' textbook)

Tags: complex-analysis

Ahlfors says that $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=i\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$ implies that $\overline{f(z)}$ is analytic.

I don't know how that is. Any help would be great.

Comment: @AlexR: I think it's fine, since this one complex-valued equation implies two real-valued equations (for the real and imaginary parts respectively).

Comment: @Semiclassical ah I oversaw that $f:\mathbb C\to\mathbb C$ implicitly :D Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: There are many dozens of questions about exercises from this book on the site. Make your question distinguishable. Also, please read the advice on [asking good questions](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/9959) to avoid questions being closed...

Comment: @900sit-upsaday- It's not an exercise. It was a statement made smack in the middle of the paragraph.

Answer (score 1):

Not enough rep to comment. Check out the Cauchy - Riemann equations and recall what $\overline{f(z)}$ means.

Comment: I think you can turn this into a proper answer if you fill out the details a bit. As it stands, though, this is quite thin.

Comment: Where is the continuity of the partial derivatives mentioned? Isn't that a pre-requisite for a function to be analytic?